# Java: Search a value in special order through a HashMap<T, Integer>

Tags: java, hashmap

i already have a working solution for my problem, but it seems a bit too much code for me so maybe you have a better idea :) I have a HashMap with a limited size of 1000 elements. When I want to put 1 more, the T with the lowest related Integer in the map should be replaced with the new one.

My present code is:

```
public boolean add(T element) {
    if (set.containsKey(element)) {
        return false;
    } else if (set.size() == length) {
        Integer searchedInteger = set.values().stream().sorted().findFirst().get();
        T searchedElement = set.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getValue().equals(searchedInteger))
                .findFirst()
                .get()
                .getKey();
        set.remove(searchedElement);
        set.put(element, 0);
        return true;
    }
    set.put(element, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thats isnt a lot of code...its like 5 lines without conditionals and returns.....

Comment: you can remove the set.put() and return true at the end of the else if clause

Comment: Maybe more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bajal oh thanks i didnt know this section

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/124741/9357) on Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first improvement you could make is to avoid `sorted().findFirst()`. Most implementations of `Stream` sort all the elements in this situation, so it's ineffiecient. It's much better to use `min` instead.

Also, there is no need to iterate over the entries twice. You can do this

```
Map.Entry<T, Integer> e = set.entrySet()
                             .stream()                                      
                             .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                             .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
set.remove(e.getKey());
```

Comment: We can also do something like `...map(Map.Entry::getKey).ifPresent(set::remove)` instead of `...orElseThrow(...)`. (Although throwing makes a lot more sense to me in this particular case.)

Comment: @Radiodef Good point. Shame there's no method that accepts a `Supplier<Throwable>` and a `Consumer<T>`.

Comment: how do i get the ifPresent part running? It doesnt accept set.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).ifPresent(set::remove)

Comment: @N-rG There's no point in doing `set.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey)` because you might just as well do `set.keySet().stream()`. You can't do `ifPresent` after `map` because `map` returns a `Stream` and `ifPresent` is a method of `Optional`. If you don't care about throwing an exception, the shortest code is probably: `set.keySet().stream().min(Comparator.comparingInt(set::get)).ifPresent(set::remove);`.

Comment: ah yes your right i missed to change map for min. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! Doing it all in one line like that makes it so easy to get confused, especially as both `Optional` and `Stream` have `map` methods.